# How to remove id from url-jquery

Tags: jquery

I have one form with submit `button`.I am getting id from `url` when page is loaded.

```
http://localhost:3000/question?id=1
```

when I click submit,I just need to remove the id from url or else I can remove it after loading the page.How to do it?
This is what I have tried, but its not working.

```
document.location.href = String( document.location.href ).replace( "#/", "" );
```

Note: Its like online examination,when I choose subject I will pass the id in url and redirects to questions page,when I click submit for 1st question  it goes to next question.on that time I wont change url.I just need to remove id from url.

Comment: split the string and pop it

Comment: By saying submit, it sounds that you are submitting a Form. Does this mean you want to change the URL that the Form sends it data to? If so, then changing `document.location.href` is definitely not going to help with that.

Comment: Its like online examination,when I choose subject I will pass the id in url and redirects to questions page,when I click submit for 1st question  it goes to next question.on that time I wont change url.I just need to remove id from url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `window.location.href.split('?')[0]`